# What is the reason behind setAccessible method of AccessibleObject class have a boolean parameter?

Tags: java, reflection, signature

I am very new in Reflection and I have a doubt like:

```
public void setAccessible(boolean flag) throws SecurityException
```

This method has a `boolen` parameter flag, which indicates the new accessibility of any fields or methods.
For an example if we are try to access a `private` method of a class from outside the class then we fetch the method using `getDeclaredMethod` and set the accessibility as `true`, so it can be invoked, like: `method.setAccessible(true);`
Now in which scenario we should use `method.setAccessible(false);` , for an example it can be used when there is a `public` method and we set the accessibility as false. But what is the need of that? Is my understanding clear?
If there is no use of `method.setAccessible(false)` then we can change the method signature like:

```
public void setAccessible() throws SecurityException
```

Comment: You don't want to leave the code under reflection in a state which the programmer of the code **did not intend**. Do you ? You used reflection to _unlock_ a piece of code for inspection, do you want to leave it _unlocked_ afterwards ?

Comment: Downvoater can you please put a comment so that i can improve my question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scenario: you removed protection from a private field with `Field.setAccessible(true),` read it and returned the field into original state with `Field.setAccessible(false).`

Comment: you can do this but that makes no effect because you do not protect the accessibilty by setting it to false again as any client can any time obtain a field instance and use setAccessible(true) again to use the field. Moreover setAccessible doesn't permanently alter the accessiblity of the field nor in a non reflection way, so that you can protect it from clients using the field in a non REFLECTION way..

Comment: Agreed, but we always have to do this. No one is going to pass the `false` value here. So why even bother to write an extra line of code?

Answer (score 19):

Probably you would never do `setAccessible(false)` in your entire life. This is because setAccessible doesn't the change the visiblity of the a member permanently. When you to something like `method.setAccessible(true)` you are allowed to make subsequent calls on **this** `method` instance even if the method in the original source is *private*.

For example consider this:

```
A.java
*******
public class A
{
   private void fun(){
     ....
   }
}

B.java
***********
public class B{

   public void someMeth(){
       Class clz = A.class; 
       String funMethod = "fun";

       Method method = clz.getDeclaredMethod(funMethod);
       method.setAccessible(true);

       method.invoke(); //You can do this, perfectly legal;

       /** but you cannot do this(below), because fun method's visibilty has been 
           turned on public only for the method instance obtained above **/

       new A().fun(); //wrong, compilation error

       /**now you may want to re-switch the visibility to of fun() on method
          instance to private so you can use the below line**/

      method.setAccessible(false);

      /** but doing so doesn't make much effect **/

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
//create class PrivateVarTest { private abc =5; and private getA() {sop()}} 


import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PrivateVariableAcc {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PrivateVarTest myClass = new PrivateVarTest();

    Field field1 = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");

    field1.setAccessible(true);

    System.out.println("This is access the private field-"
            + field1.get(myClass));

    Method mm = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getA");

    mm.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("This is calling the private method-"
            + mm.invoke(myClass, null));

}

}
```